# How to verify that exception was thrown by a mock when it was caught within the code under test?

Tags: java, exception, junit, mockito

In Java/Junit/Mockito, it is fairly easy to simulate an exception (doThrow() etc.), and fairly easy to verify when an exception is thrown and not caught (assertThrows() etc.). But what if exception was successfully simulated using doThrow, but then subsequently caught in the main code - how the test can know that it was ever thrown?

Consider following code snippet:

```
public void doFullOpeartion() {

    try {
        optionalService.blink();
    }
    catch (IOException exception) {
        // No operation needed
    }
```

And the following test code:

```
doThrow(IOException.class).when(mockOptionalService).blink();

classUnderTest.doFullOperation();

// ??? - how do we know that IOException was thrown
```

If in the catch block in the main code we had some code that could be verified, the problem becomes moot. But what if we don't?

Comment: It sounds like a strange problem. Doesn't the test only care that an exception was thrown or not thrown? Which is what `assertThrows` does. You want your test to assert that an exception was thrown, caught and not rethrown?

Comment: Can't you do `verify(mockOptionalService, times(1)).blink()` in combination with `doThrow`? That would imply not just that *if* it's called, it should throw, but also that it must be called (and thus throw). The exception or lack of exception in the test is the indication whether or not it was caught.

Comment: "You want your test to assert that an exception was thrown, caught and not rethrown?" - yes, pretty much. The overall purpose of this test is to verify that this particular execution path does not break the code. I know I can verify unused doReturn (or verify that they were called once) - but is it possible to verify unused doThrow?

Answer (score 1):

I prefer tddavies' answer (just verify that the mock was called - because you know that calling it means it throws). But here's another solution which perhaps makes what you're trying to assert a bit more explicit.

`doAnswer` is the more general purpose Mockito primitive, which can either return a value or throw. In there you can just maintain a counter.

```
AtomicInteger blinkIOExceptions = new AtomicInteger();
doAnswer(invocation -> {
    blinkIOExceptions.incrementAndGet();
    throw new IOException();
}).when(mockOptionalService).blink();

assertEquals(1, blinkIOExceptions.get());
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you can check that the exception is actually thrown, but you can verify that the method you stubbed to throw an exception was actually called. See the example below, where we control whether the method is called, and a test fails when it doesn't get called:

```
package org.example;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.junit.jupiter.MockitoExtension;

import java.io.IOException;

import static org.mockito.Mockito.doThrow;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.verify;

class ToTest {
    private final InjectedClass injectedClass;

    ToTest(InjectedClass injectedClass) {
        this.injectedClass = injectedClass;
    }

    public void doIt(boolean callMethod) {
        try {
            if (callMethod) {
                injectedClass.mightThrow();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // ignore (this seems like a bad idea...
        }
    }
}

interface InjectedClass {
    void mightThrow() throws IOException;
}

@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class AppTest {
    @Mock
    InjectedClass injectedClass;
    @InjectMocks
    ToTest toTest;

    @Test
    public void passingTest() throws IOException {
        doThrow(IOException.class).when(injectedClass).mightThrow();
        toTest.doIt(true);
        verify(injectedClass).mightThrow();
    }

    @Test
    public void failingTest() throws IOException {
        doThrow(IOException.class).when(injectedClass).mightThrow();
        toTest.doIt(false);
        verify(injectedClass).mightThrow();
    }
}
```